# When session_start gets fired, get Cookies not updating value in Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies

When session_start fired, I get the cookie value which is not updated value.
On my investigation, when this matter happend when using Mobile Safari, and first request is ajax call.
Please help me.

■get cookie
 this method is the getcookie value.

```
public static string GetCookie(String Key)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = null;
        try
        {
            cookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Key];
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            LogWriter.PutError(ex2);
            return null;
        }

        if (cookie == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return cookie.Value;
    }
```

■set cookie
 this method is set cookie value.

```
public static void SetCookie(String Key, String Value, DateTime ExpiryDate)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Key];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(Key);
            cookie.Value = Value;
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cookie.Value = Value;
        }
        cookie.Expires = ExpiryDate;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

■session_start()

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogWriter.PutInfo(CLASSNAME, "Session_Start-S" + Session.SessionID);
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Session[KIinterface.Constants.CommonConstant.COMPANY_ID] == null)
            {
                string oldGuid = CommonUtil.GetCookie("id");//get not updated value

                if (oldGuid == null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: What is the reason behind accessing Session and Cookie values at Session_Start?